# Unable to view my Drupal site correctly via IP address

Tags: php, drupal, hosting

When I visit my Drupal site through a URL like www.example.com, it displays correctly,
but when I try to visit through the IP it goes to the setting.php file and asks me to set it up from the start.

I've been working on this two days, but cannot find any solution.  I'd be very thankful if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the settings.php file from sites/example.com to the default folder.  It is the default fold that will control what settings are used for ip address sites.N